# MetroFramework баги

Tags: c#, winforms

Вот как выглядит моя MetroFramework форма в visual studio [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот  так выглядит моя форма при запуске [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже и файлы сохранял ,и visual studio перезагружал , но проблема не уходит. Как её решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось , это самый обычный глюк этого фреймворка , через некоторое время форма загрузилась с верными цветовыми гаммами .